# Streamreader reading the same line multiple times C#

Tags: c#, readfile, streamreader

My old method (other than being wrong in general) takes too long to get multiple lines from a file and then store the parameters into a dictionary.
Essentially it's open file, grab every second line one at a time, modify the line then store the data (line pos and the first element of the line (minus) ">") close the file and then repeat.

```
for (int i = 0; i < linecount - 1; i += 2)
{
    string currentline = File.ReadLines 
    (datafile).Skip(i).Take(1).First();
    string[] splitline = currentline.Split(' ');
    string filenumber = splitline[0].Trim('>');
}   for (int i = 0; i < linecount - 1; i += 2)
```

Comment: `An item with the same key has already been added.` What was the exact value of `datanumber` when it occurred? Have you considered using `[]` rather than `Add`?

Comment: `File.ReadLines(dataFile).Count()` reads the whole file just to get a line count. Do you *really* need to know how many lines before reading it? Your new implementation doesn't appear to. Removing that line should shave some time for starters.

Comment: @madreflection agreed, that was from the old code, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: The last line of your `while` should be `line = sr.ReadLine();`. Otherwise you keep looking only at the first line.

Comment: @mjwills that solved it, thank you. If you submit that as the answer I'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you only ever read the first line of the file. To solve this you need to ensure you call `sr.ReadLine()` on every iteration through the loop. This would look like:

```
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(datafile))
{
    string line = sr.ReadLine();
    while (line != null)
    {
        count = count ++;
        if (count % 2 == 0)
        {
            string[] splitline = line.Split(' ');
            string datanumber = splitline[0].Trim('>');
            index.Add(datanumber, count);
        }

        line = sr.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This means on each iteration, the value of `line` will be a new value (from the next line of the file).

Answer (score 2):

You need to read next line inside while loop, otherwise loop body will always analyse first line (that's why there are Dictionary error) and never exist:

```
while (line != null)
{
    // your current code here
    line = sr.ReadLine();
}
```